# Titlesec Problem, Won't Compile

Tags: titlesec

I came back to a .tex file I haven't used in a couple of years and it no longer compiles. I've narrowed down the problem to the titlesec package (I think); if I can find out why this MWE won't compile maybe I'll find my answer:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

   \documentclass[paper=4.25in:6.75in,pagesize=auto,fontsize=9.5pt,headings=small,BCOR=.25mm,openany,DIV=16]{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2ex}{1ex}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{1ex}{0ex}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0.5ex}{0ex}
\vspace{-1mm}

\begin{document}
\chapter{red}
\blindtext
\section{blue}
\blindtext
\subsection{green}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{yellow}




\end{document}
```

This is the error thrown:

```
test+001.tex:17: Missing number, treated as zero. 
<to be read again>
                                }
1.17 \section{blue}
?
```

If I add these lines the tex file compiles:

```
\titleformat{\section}
 {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
 {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
 {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should cite the error you get. Compiles fine on my system.

Comment: What's `\vspace{-1mm}` supposed to do in the preamble?

Comment: @egreg It was a suggestion, probably found on this forum, to reduce size and space. I was trying to squeeze a 400 page book into a much smaller format.

Comment: Using `titlesec` with the `koma-script` classes isn't recommended.

Comment: @daleif: If I remove the \usepackage{titlesec} and the subsequent \titlespacing commands it compiles fine on mine as well. However, with them, no luck.

Comment: @user26732 In that position it does nothing at all.

Comment: Compiles without error for me. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: Texlive 2015, MacOS.

Comment: There was a bug in titlesec once. Tryvto update that package.

Comment: Version 2.10.2.

Comment: You should install TeX Live 2017 and use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` instead of `titlesec` to change spacing of the headings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error can be fixed by a simple update of classes and packages or upgrade of TeX Live.

Comment: Upgrading the package didn't fix the problem. Maybe a 1 gb download of Tex Live 2017 will, but it's disappointing that a text that once compiled now all of sudden is broken. One of the virtues of LaTeX is that it doesn't get broken by annual upgrades.