# Adding horizontal line before and after chapter heading -- in scrbook

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning

If you use the documentclass book or scrbook, new chapters look rather boring: it's just the headline plus the number, for exmaple:

[image]

So instead one might want to add horizontal lines before and after -- which makes it look a bit more pleasing I think:

[image]

How that's done is described [here on Stackoverflow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456086/how-to-create-horizontal-line-before-and-after-chapter-heading-but-not-in-table), the adapted code is re-produced here:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Surrounds all chapter titles by lines (see screenshot),
% which includes the titles in the TOC and list of figures and tables
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\huge}
{\filleft\Large\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}
{3ex}
{\titlerule\vspace{1.5ex}\filright}
[\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]

% The following code removes the lines (that are added above)
% from the TOC and list of figures and tables
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]
{\bfseries\huge}
{}
{0pt}
{\filright}

\begin{document}

% Puts TOC and list of figures on tables on a single pages
% makes sense for minimal working examples so that one 
% doesn't have to scroll for ages just to check appearance
\tableofcontents
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\listoffigures
\let\clearpage\relax
\listoftables
\endgroup

\newcommand{\ShortLorem}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibu-
lum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. }

\chapter{First Chapter Headline}

\ShortLorem

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.35\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Dummy caption\label{fig:dummyFig}}
\end{figure}

\ShortLorem

\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    A & B\\
    \hline
    a & b
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Dummy caption\label{tab:dummyTab}}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\ShortLorem

\chapter{Second Chapter Headline}

\ShortLorem

\section{First Section in 2nd Chapter}

\ShortLorem

\section{Second Section in 2nd Chapter}

\ShortLorem

\end{document}
```

Just for the sake of completeness: My question (see below) is a variant on the one I linked. The original question asks how to prevent these additional lines in the TOC and list of figures and tables. That's what the second code block in the beginning (`The following code removes...`) does. Its impact illustrated in the following graphic:

[image]

(If you find all of above useful, please like the Q and A in the [orginal question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456086/how-to-create-horizontal-line-before-and-after-chapter-heading-but-not-in-table)! I just improved the code a bit (added comments, removed pointsless packages), and added screenshots.)

**Now, my question:**

*How do I get this code to work when I change the documentclass from book to scrbook?*

When I do that I receive the following error message:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.74 \section{First Section in 2nd Chapter}
```

I do not know why ... Can this be 'repaired'? The sole reason why I use scrbook instead of book is since the former provides *much* more space, i.e., the borders are smaller. I wasn't aware of any other changes so far (like the ones that clearly cause the above code not to work anymore). Help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Do not use package `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class. If really want to do this see [Conflict between titlesec package and scrbook class after most recent update of TeXLive2019](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511057/43317). To change the layout of the chapter title redefine `\chapterlinesformat` and `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`. Example: [KOMA-Script line above and below chapter title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273363/43317).

Comment: If you want to use the page layout of `scrbook` together with class `article`, load KOMA-Script package `typearea`.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting the following code makes it work:

```
\titleformat{\section}
 {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
 {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
 {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
```

(Taken from [Stackoverflow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386301/titlesec-problem-wont-compile). But I'm happy for further explanations, e.g., why adding the `titlesec` package causes the problem.)